# Stripping null byte blocks with a sparse file?

Tags: linux, dd, sparse-files

I've created a sparse file with `dd`. How do I copy contents of another file there, leaving all the zero blocks unallocated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a file that was originally sparse and expanded be made re-sparse](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52012/can-a-file-that-was-originally-sparse-and-expanded-be-made-re-sparse)

Comment: That question and answer are a bit unclear, but I think they show a fundamental misunderstanding.  If you overwrite a file using `cp`, the overwritten file disappears.  It doesn't matter if that file used to be sparse; these things are not contagious.

Comment: Interesting, but I assume that the source file still exists. The question is if I can preserve this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is apparently to use `cp --sparse=always`. My first attempt was with writing some Python code, but unfortunately the MD5 sums didn't match (could anyone tell me why? the code's in edit history).

Comment: The filesystem block size usually isn't 512B - more often it is 4KB.

Comment: You say that might be the reason that MD5 sums didn't match?

Comment: No, filesystem gives you zeros where it finds an unallocated block, so the error had to be in your script. The block size is important for other reason: if you seek by 6 empty 512B sectors, then one with some data an then again seek say 4 empty sectors, you save nothing, because the data in the one sector causes the fs to allocate whole 4K block.

Comment: GNU `tar` also has the `-S, --sparse` option to handle sparse files effectively, btw.

Comment: @d33tah your python code is losing a byte every time it seeks because of the `-1` in the seek target, which isn't necessary. You should seek ahead a full 512 bytes each time.