# Swap (exchange) two big files in limited environment

Tags: files, utilities

Let's say I have two flash memory devices 1GB capacity each. Let's also say each device contains one big file ~ 1GB size. Assuming, I have limited (64MB) RAM and no hard disk drive, **what is the shortest way to swap this two files ?**

I mean: if file `a` is on device `A` and `b` is on device `B`, I want swap operation to place `a` on `B` and `b` on `A`.

I know there is no exact linux tool to do that according to [this discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2012-12/msg00029.html).

I am interested in shortest way to achieve my goal. If that way will be too long, I probably will have to implement my own dedicated solution that will perform swap chunk by chunk, am I right ?

Comment: When copying the files chunk by chunk, you could use something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52029/28235) to convert the chunks you've already copied to sparse holes to free space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as both drives are full, or almost full, I doubt there is a pretty solution. It should be possible to loop over dd commands though.
Something like

```
#This code is completely untested, 
#do NOT just copy paste and use it without proper testing
while [[ $((i*chunkSize)) -lt fileSize ]]; do
  dd skip=$i seek=$i bs=$chunkSize count=1 if=fileA of=tmpFileInMemory
  dd skip=$i seek=$i bs=$chunkSize count=1 if=fileB of=FileA
  dd skip=$i seek=$i bs=$chunkSize count=1 if=tmpFileInMemory of=fileB
done
```

Some checks are needed for when fileA and fileB have different sizes.