# Strange discrepancy of file sizes from ls

Tags: ls, size

I've been using `ls -sh` to check file sizes ever since 1997 or so, but today something strange happened:

```
ninja@vm:foo$ ls -sh
total 98M
1,0M app   
64M app_fake_signed.sbp  
800K loader  
804K loader_fake_signed.sbp  
1,0M web   
32M web_fake_signed.sbp
```

The `app` and `web` files were not supposed to be much smaller than their signed counterparts, and I spent several hours debugging the signing program. After finding nothing, by chance I happened to look at the files in a Samba share, to find them very similar in size. I checked again:

```
ninja@vm:foo$ ls -lh
total 98M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja  63M lut  4 14:13 app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja  64M lut  4 14:13 app_fake_signed.sbp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja 800K lut  4 14:13 loader
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja 801K lut  4 14:13 loader_fake_signed.sbp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja  31M lut  4 14:13 web
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ninja ninja  32M lut  4 14:14 web_fake_signed.sbp
```

I'm speechless? Why does `ls -s` show the `app` and `web` to be 1MB in size, while they are actually 63 and 32MB, respectively?

This was Xubuntu 14.04 running in VirtualBox on Windows, if it makes any difference.

**Edit:**
The files `app`, `web` and `loader` are all created by a bash script (not of my design) which runs `dd if=/dev/urandom of=app bs=$BLOCK count=1 seek=...` in a loop. The signing program, written in C, takes these files and writes their signed versions to the disk, prepending and appending a binary signature to each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the `-s` option to `ls`.

A file's size and the amount of disk space it takes up may differ.  Consider for example, if you open new file, seek 1G into it, and write "something", the OS doesn't allocate 1G (plus the space for "something") on disk, it allocates only the space for "something" -- this is called a *sparse file*.

I wrote a small C program to create such a file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/foo.dat", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);

    if (fd > 0) {
        const off_t GIG = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Seek 1G into the file
        lseek(fd, GIG, SEEK_SET);

        // Write something
        write(fd, "hello", sizeof "hello");

        close(fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running that program I get:

```
$ ls -lh /tmp/foo.dat
-rw------- 1 user group 1.1G Feb  4 15:25 /tmp/foo.dat
```

But using `-s`, I get:

```
$ ls -sh /tmp/foo.dat
4.0K /tmp/foo.dat
```

So a 4K block was allocated on disk to store "hello" (and 4K is the smallest unit of allocation for my filesystem).

In your case, it looks like `app` and `web` are such sparse files.

Comment: That's brilliant, I didn't know about sparse files, thanks! I just wonder why it's no longer sparse after the signing tool is done with it, I will probably investigate some more. :)

Comment: It might be that writing to the beginning and end of the file after seeking through it causes the sparsity to get eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -s` lists the amount of storage space used by the file's content (excluding space used for metadata). This can differ from the file size in two ways:

- In most cases, the file size is rounded up to a whole number of blocks. The size of a block is typically 512B to 4kB but it depends on the filesystem (and some filesystems don't have this concept).
- If the file is encoded in some way, e.g. if it's compressed, the file size could be less (or more).

Unix filesystems support a crude form of compression called [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file): if a block in a file consists entirely of null bytes, it doesn't need to be stored at all; the filesystem puts a special marker instead of a block number in the list of blocks that store the file's content. This compression method isn't systematic: if a program writes a bunch of null bytes, they'll be stored. However, Unix also allows a program to write past the end of a file. In that case, the file is expanded with null bytes, but if those bytes make up a whole block or more, such whole null blocks are not stored.

When you write `dd seek=…`, the `dd` program seeks to the given position before it starts writing. In your case, taking `app` as an example, the position seems to have been about 62MB past the end of the file, so there are about 62MB worth of null bytes that are stored implicitly, in nonexistent blocks. This storage detail is not exposed to applications (unless they use non-portable interfaces to find out, which very few do), so when the signing program reads its input, all it knows is that there are about 63MB of data, and so it writes 63MB, of which about 62MB are null bytes, to its output file.

If you really need the disk space, you can [make the file sparse after the fact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52012/can-a-file-that-was-originally-sparse-and-expanded-be-made-re-sparse). This is rarely done because most files don't have big blocks of zeros so running a tool to find them would be a big waste of time.